# Highlight, Disable specific days in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here, i want to achieve following

1. Highlight all holidays in date-picker
2. Disable specific days in date-picker
3. Disable specific weekends in date-picker

I have snippets of each separately, but i want all together

Fiddle:[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/78/)

**Highlight holidays**

```
var holydays = ['10/17/2013', '10/18/2013', '11/2/2013'];

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < holydays.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(holydays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];

}

$(function () {
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        inline: true,
        numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    });
});
```

**Disable specific days**

```
var disabledDays = ["10-20-2013", "10-21-2013", "11-15-2013", "11-17-2013"];
    function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
        for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
```

**Disable Weekends**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#availability" ).datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            inline: true,
            numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
        });
    });
```

Could anyone help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In "Disable specific days" the for loop is not needed
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) 
The inner code is enough
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change :

```
$(function () {
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        inline: true,
        numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        beforeShowDay: setCustomDate // <-----change function
    });
});
```

add function :

```
function setCustomDate(date) {
    var clazz = "";
    var arr1 = highlightDays(date);
    if (arr1[1] != "") clazz = arr1[1];

    var arr2 = disableAllTheseDays(date);
    var arr3 = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

    return [(!arr2[0] || !arr3[0]) ? false : true, clazz];
}
```

Comment: if have js array of closed days how can we pass that

Answer (score 2):

We are now in 2014, and a minimal code is required.
Here is my way to disable days.

my variable 'specific' , 0 <= specific <= 7

```
in my demo :
```

`1 = sunday`
`2 = saturday`
`4 = Monday to friday`

```
if specific == 5 that mean 4 + 1 so i allow Monday till friday + sunday.
```

7 means all days allowed to pick.
notice that I only allow to pick starting now to Month + 1

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate:0,
    maxDate: '+1M-1D',
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        if(day == 6)
            return [(specific & 2) > 0, ''];
        else if(day == 0)
            return [(specific & 1) > 0, ''];
        else
            return [(specific & 4) > 0, ''];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future references. Since I was looking for the same thing and found these same function to disable days in a lot of different places:

http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/
https://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

```
var disabledDays = ["10-20-2013", "10-21-2013", "11-15-2013", "11-17-2013"];

function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
     var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
     for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
         if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
             return [false];
         }
     }
     return [true];
}
```

But since you're using inArray, the for is not needed, resulting in this simpler and more efficient function:

```
var disabledDays = ["4-2-2016", "4-4-2016"];

function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
     var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
     if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) return [false];
     return [true];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. Placed before closing body tag.

```
function DisableMonday(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
     if (day == 1) {
     return [false,"","Unavailable"] ; 
     } else { 
     return [true] ;
     } 
    }
    jQuery(function($){
        $('input[name="datum"]').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', DisableMonday).datepicker('refresh');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the allowed_weekdays variable for your requirement
using this you can restrict the dates for the particular weekday

> var allowed_weekdays = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
> // 1 for Sunday to 7 for Saturday
>
> ```
>     // Function to check if a date is in the allowed weekdays
>     function isAllowedWeekday(date) {
>         var day = date.getDay() + 1;  // Adding 1 to match your allowed_weekdays array
>         return allowed_weekdays.includes(day.toString());
>     }
>
>     // Initialize datepicker
>     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
>         dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
>         beforeShowDay: function(date) {
>             // Disable all dates except those in allowed weekdays
>             return [isAllowedWeekday(date), ""];
>         }
>     }).attr("readonly", "readonly");
> ```