# How to disable jQuery DataPicker specific date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to create an interface where user can Enable/Disable date on datapicker click. So, I am using onselect event which returns current selected date but, I am looking for the object which can be enabled or disabled.

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: nationalDays,
        onSelect: function (date, obj) {

            //How do I get clicked object


        }

    });
```

Comment: In what respect are you trying to disable/enable it? Are you trying to remove it from the datepicker itself? As in make it unselectable? In which case how would the user re-enable it?

Comment: You want to disable a date when it is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful this Please try:-

1st. http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

Or

2nd. [Highlight, Disable specific days in jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395558/highlight-disable-specific-days-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: I want to disable it only when user selects it. The goal is to allow user to select the dates from datepicker which he wishes to disable

Comment: If i understand you then, In 1st link you can set dates which you disable in jquery variable "disabledDays"