# How to integrate Date Picker with HTML

Tags: jquery, html

How to integrate date picker in HTML

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pepper-ginder-custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettify.css">
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/lang-css.js"></script>
<script src="js/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $function(){
    $('#custom-methods').multiDatesPicker()
};

</script>
<body>
Date : <input type="text"  id="custom-methods"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

this is how I am doing, date picker is here - 
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

I want to integrate that.

Comment: Hey where is `<head>...</head>` tag? Try enclosing the `<link>` and `<script>` tags in it.

Comment: It should be `$(function() { // Code here });` and not `$function(){..};`. Try fixing that.

Comment: its like that only. script tag I have replaced with below comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this .

```
$(Document).ready(function() {// everything comes under document.ready 

$('#custom-methods').multiDatesPicker(); // if you script working this should attach to textbox .

});
```

I tried using date-picker which is working fine for me . Possible try and debug using chrome or firebug to check script working or not and let me know just in case

**ORDER SHOULD BE :**
//css comes first Later on .

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> // NEXT to this anything 
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>
<script src="js/lang-css.js"></script>
<script src="js/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
```

Regards

Comment: while I am clicking on Inspect Element these are errors over there -
<pre>Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.ui.core.js:319
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.ui.datepicker.js:1826
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: PR is not defined lang-css.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'multiDatesPicker' of undefined jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js:452
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function</pre>

Comment: yes it may be the issue . would you make the order of scripts as mentioned in my answer

Comment: You probably haven't loaded jQuery properly if you are getting "jQuery is not defined".

Comment: in what order, i am not able to find

Comment: jquery.js comes first as always . try and let me know . IE may have datepicker compatibility issues and also add jQuery UI 1.8.24.js next to jquery.js . Hope this does it

Comment: Yea it worked Mann, you are actually cool... Can you help me with its enhancement? I need to disable all the past dates and dates after 20 days of current date, how to do that?

Comment: Glad it helped . Well make it as a separate question so people can look and help you up .And i will look into it. Cheers

Comment: You can look into this if you are interested you can solve by urself Lol its the best way to learn . Way to start : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395558/highlight-disable-specific-days-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

In script tags

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('#custom-methods').multiDatesPicker(); });
```

Answer (score -2):

use these links:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/css/mdp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/css/pepper-ginder-custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/css/prettify.css">


<!--<script src="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>-->



<script src="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js">    
</script>
<script src="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/js/lang-css.js"></script>
<script src="C:/wamp/www/PouyaPlugin/Multidatepicker/js/prettify.js"></script>


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">    
 </script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">    
</script>
<script src="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js">    
</script>
```

Comment: A lot of the links you provided are local to your computer.  You should either edit your post so that it includes links that are not dependent on your computer, or remove them all together.