# I am using Bootstrap Datapicker show date in other place and highlight week end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use the Datapicker as a Calendar and want to selected date other "div" and weed ends change color  can you  provide my problem solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-datepicker-week-end a {
    color: red !important;
}
#calendar
{
background-color:#222;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").datepicker();
});

</script>

  
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</form>




</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM0f5.png)

see above image 10th place i want selected date then and week end select then change color

Comment: to highlight a specific date, this answer can solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397191/5644965 with `beforeShowDay`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the DevTools from Chrome browser is a good helper, just hint F12.

After running your code with DevTools open, you will see the error message in the Console panel:
Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4.

So just change your jQuery version to 1.12.4, jQueryUI version to 1.12.1, and the code works.

Good luck!