# various JQuery datepicker allow only last day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

On my form I've various JQuery datepickers and I'll only allow last day for each month.
Here is code in a loop (X different datepickers are generated depending of number of users in a group):

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text"
readonly
placeholder="<?php _e(DATE_FORMAT, TEXT_DOMAIN); ?>"
data-minDate="<?php echo date(API_DATE_FORMAT,$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']); ?>"
class="input_datepicker form-control input_user_edit"
name="input_block_access"
<?php echo (!empty($user->getDate()) && (int)date('Y',
    strtotime($user->getDate())) !== 1) ? 'value="'.$user->getDate().'"' : ''; ?>
    onchange="disableFields(this)"
>
```

Now I'm trying to disable all days except last day of each month. Here is javascript code:

```
jQuery(function() { 
              function getLastDayOfYearAndMonth(year, month)
              {
                  return(new Date((new Date(year, month + 1, 1)) - 1)).getDate();                    
              }
              jQuery("#ui-datepicker-div").datepicker({
                beforeShowDay:LastDay
              });

              jQuery(".input_datepicker").each(function(){
                jQuery(this).datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay:LastDay
                });
                console.log(jQuery(this).datepicker("widget"));
              });

              function LastDay(date){
                  // getDate() returns the day [ 0 to 31 ]                    
                  var last = getLastDayOfYearAndMonth(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
                  console.log(date.getDate()+"->"+last);
                  if (date.getDate() == last)
                      return [true, ""];
                  return [false, ""];
              }
          })
```

Unfortunately the different datepickers show all days.

EDIT: generated HTML code from Wordpress:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 680px; left: 570px; z-index: 1; display: block;">...</div>

<form>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="input_cancel_access">End Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" readonly="" placeholder="jj.mm.aaaa" data-date-format="mm/" data-mindate="2021-12-31" class="input_datepicker form-control input_user_edit hasDatepicker" name="input_cancel_access" value="" onchange="disablePasswordInput(this)" id="dp1611299063605">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
...
<form>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="input_cancel_access">End Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" readonly="" placeholder="jj.mm.aaaa" data-date-format="mm/" data-mindate="2021-12-31" class="input_datepicker form-control input_user_edit hasDatepicker" name="input_cancel_access" value="31.01.2020" onchange="disablePasswordInput(this)" id="dp1611299063603">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope somebody can point the error with this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight, Disable specific days in jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395558/highlight-disable-specific-days-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: @melancia thank you for answer but unfortunately this is not a valid answer for my code (already tried it). If I had only one datepicker it would probably work but I couldn't find a solution for many datepickers on the same page.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one element with the same Id? Show us the generated markup, not the PHP code.

Comment: @melancia, thank you for your time. I've edited the post with the cleaned up code as the page is quite huge (wordpress generated). Thank you for your time